# Is this map of Israel-occupied territory accurate?

Tags: politics, israel

There's an image going around Facebook, showing Israel's occupied territory over the last few decades:

[image: Isreale 1946-2010]

I have seen at least two people (both Christian Zionists) criticize this map as "very biased" because it was created by an anti-semite.  My follow-up questions to these critics have gone completely unanswered. Personally, I don't care if it was created by Adolf Hitler himself, if the map is accurate.

Is this map accurate?  If not, or if there is some sort of room for interpretation, what are its chief failures?

Comment: The apparent interpretation may be biased and there are clear inaccuracies. The entire country was British in 1946 so the map isn't mapping the same definition as the later maps. The 2010 map is clearly wrong as there is **no** israeli land in gaza since the israeli withdrawal. It also ignores the reason why the UN plan was not the outcome (the arabs invaded and lost the subsequent war on different boundaries). And Israel occupied Sinai in 1967 *but handed it back*.

Comment: The 2010 map looks roughly similar to this [New York Times map](http://www.nytimes.com/imagepages/2006/01/25/international/20060125_palestianELECTION_GRAPHIC.html) from 2006 of "areas of formal Palestinian control", except that oddly the colours seem to be reversed in the Gaza Strip. The Gaza Strip should now be full shaded dark. For credibility reasons, the pale grey in 2010 should shrink to match the dark areas of 1967 (in fact the 1948 ceasefire lines).

Comment: If the third picture is showing Israel before the 1967 war, shouldn't it be stating that the green areas are Jordan and Egypt? http://proisraelbaybloggers.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/bluestar-israels-sacrifices-for-peace.html

Comment: As a more general point, my default assumption about anything I see on facebook is that it's false. The first thing I'd do is ask the author of the image to prove that it's true, rather than for the critics of the image to prove that it's false.

Comment: Much better infographic with sources [here](http://awesome.good.is/transparency/web/1110/cartographic-regression/flat.html), as a side note, please see my comments on the answer as the 2010 map seems to be correct (most of the West Bank is actually still under Israeli control)...

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: That may be good general advice, but in this case, Christian Zionism has its own obvious bias (a desire to show Israel as the innocent victim, rather than as an oppressor), which gives me reason to question that position.

Comment: @Flimzy Everyone has their own biases, however, with the maps, there is only a single truth.

Comment: @Sklivvz While much of the west bank is under military control, **none** of Gaza is making the 2010 map wrong in at least that detail.

Comment: It's obvious the author of this map didn't put much effort into it - so it's safe to assume it's inaccurate. Why? In 1946 there was no "Palestine", rather it was "The British Mandate of Palestine". In 1967 (unclear if pre-war or post-war) the green area was Jordan, not Palestine.  In 2010 all of Gaza is Palestinian - not just pockets of it. Israel pulled out in 2004. Also, the Golan Heights are now part of Israel. Additionally, there are important time periods missing that are crucial to the story.

Comment: This map here: https://aijac.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mor-525x420.jpg shows an entirely oppsite picture. In short: there was no de-facto Palestinian rule over Palestine until the Oslo accords in 1993, in which Palestinians received a large part of Judea, Samaria and Gaza. In 2005, they received all of Gaza. So their territory is expanding - not shrinking. Source: https://aijac.org.au/fresh-air/disappearing-palestine-the-maps-that-lie/

Comment: I will add a link to land-owning map in 1945 [to myself] https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/17b4bcg/jewisharab_1945_landownership_map_in_the_mandate/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There are inaccuracies and biases in the map, however it seems to be based on facts.

There is a well sourced infographic, which is very similar.

[image: Loss of land]

[Cartographic Regression: Good.Is](https://www.good.is/infographics/infographic-palestine-s-shifting-borders)

- Prior to 1917, the region was part of the Ottoman Empire. The area shown as "1917 Palestine" was then the Mutasarrifate of Jerusalem, the western part of the Vilayet of Syria and the southern part of the Vilayet of Beirut.
- In 1917, during the first world war, in response to an attack on a British Protectorate  by the Ottoman army, [Ottoman Syria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Syria) was invaded and occupied by British and French forces, this became the [Occupied Enemy Territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupied_Enemy_Territory_Administration). The OETA south region corresponds with the area identified as "1917 Palestine".
- In 1920 the borders of "mandatory Palestine" were defined by the League of Nations. This area is what is shown in the infographic as "1917 Palestine"
- 1920-1948, [Palestine under British Mandate](http://www.passia.org/palestine_facts/MAPS/1923-1948-british-mandate.html)
- Your infographic for Palestine in 1946 shows some parts under Israeli control. That doesn't make sense.
- [The Population of Palestine Prior to 1948](http://www.mideastweb.org/palpop.htm)
- [Palestine 1878 - 1927](http://www.theglobaleducationproject.org/mideast/info/maps/palestine-1878-1927-map.html)

  - In 1946, as far as I can tell, the boundaries were exactly the same.
  - In 1947 a plan was proposed. Your infographic correctly mentions it is the "UN plan".
- [UN GA 181 - Annex A](http://mideastweb.org/un_palestine_partition_map_1947.htm)

  - In 1949, after the [first Arab-Israeli War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_War) (which Israel won) Palestine was reduced to two territories, Gaza and West Bank which were under control by Egypt and Jordan, respectively. Your infographic does not show this map.
- [Detailed Map of Palestine Showing Armistice Lines of Israel and Jordan (1949)](http://www.mideastweb.org/sc62.htm)
- [1949 Israel/Palestine Map](http://www.theglobaleducationproject.org/mideast/info/maps/israel-1949-map.html)

  - In 1967, after the [Six-Day War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Day_War), Israel militarily occupied these territories. Your map shows them as "Palestine", but doesn't mention they were occupied by Israel.
- [Israel and the Occupied Territories](http://www.theglobaleducationproject.org/mideast/info/maps/israel-and-occupied-territories-map.html)

  - At present, Israel has given back control of part of the territories to Palestinians. The map shows areas "A" and "B" (according to UN terminology), which means zones under at least civil control by the Palestinian Authority.
- [UN Map of West bank (2008)](http://www.ochaopt.org/documents/OCHAoPt_ClsrMp_WB0106_En.pdf)
- [B'TSELEM Map of West bank (2008)](http://www.btselem.org/download/separation_barrier_map_eng.pdf)
- [CIA map of the Palestinian Authority controlled areas](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/West_Bank_July_2008_CIA_remote-sensing_map_3000px.jpg)

As a personal note, it is a very well known fact that Israel has annexed more and more lands as a result of political pressure and winning wars. It would be wildly misleading, though, not to mention that [Israel was involved in many of these wars as a *defending party*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Israel) and that they have been giving back control to the [Palestinian National Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_National_Authority) of some of the land.

Comment: Do you have a citation that Gaza is occupied by Israel, as claimed by the infographic at the top of your answer?

Comment: Why all the down votes on this answer? Can those who think it's a bad answer explain why, for the benefit of those of us who are trying to understand the situation?

Comment: @Flimzy the whole post leaves a nagging feeling of political bias and voting-by-clique (on both sides)... :-(

Comment: @Sklivvz has anyone added any citations that Gaza is occupied by Israel to this answer since my November 27 comment?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it's in the UN documents

Comment: @Sklivvz can you summarize the UN documents stating that Gaza is occupied by Israel?

Comment: "It would be wildly misleading, though, not to mention that Israel was involved in many of these wars as a defending party ..." That's not quite correct. The conflict has its roots in mis-governance by British colonizers who adopted the divide an rule policy.

Comment: "Your infographic for Palestine in 1946 shows some parts under Israeli control. That doesn't make sense. " -> Note that the OP's infographics calls those parts as "Jewish Land" and not "Israel Land". It seems to map pretty well with Jewish-owned land under British mandate, which covered about 7% of Palestine. Of course, comparing private property before 1948 with state-controlled territory after 1948 is debatable, but it does make some sense. However, the infographics is incorrect when it all the rest of Palestine as "Palestinian Land". There were public land and land owned by non-Arabs too.

Comment: @Skliwz I feel like the major shortcoming of the map in the OP is that it shows Palestine-controlled land as shrinking between 1967 and 2010 when in fact Israel has not occupied any Palestine land between those years, only returned control of some of it. Or did I get something wrong here? (I see it as the major shortcoming because it seems to establish a trend that's the reverse of what actually happened.)

Answer (score 60):

There are several issues with these maps.

- Map of 1946.  There was no country of Palestine.  The entire area was under British control. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Palestine). It might be a better idea to have a map of land owned by Jewish vs Arab hands.  <s>I doubt that an accurate map like that exists.</s>.  (Per @Evargalo, map like that [exists](https://unispal.un.org/DPA/DPR/unispal.nsf/0/A73996728BA8B94785256D560060CD1A), it provides more proof of the inadequacy of the 1946 map - see comments for further detail).  Furthermore, 10 miles south of Jerusalem, it's pretty much all desert which is very sparsely populated to this day.  So, no, not accurate at all. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negev#Demography).
- Map of 1947. This map of the UN partition plan is accurate. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Partition_Plan_for_Palestine). However, it never ever came to be, as the nearby Arab states invaded Israel shortly after UN approved the partition (in 1948, iirc). [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_War).
- Map of 1967. This map is not accurate at all.  It's actually the situation as it was after the war for independence (mentioned above) concluded. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_War#1949_Armistice_Agreements).  Following the six-day war in 1967, Israel actually conquered everything you see on the map (either marked Israel or Palestine), plus the Gaza strip and Sinai peninsula from Egypt (area much larger than Israel).  [Source](http://www.mfa.gov.il/MFA/Facts+About+Israel/Israel+in+Maps/June+10-+1967-+Israel+After+the+Six+Day+War.htm).  Israel subsequently gave back all land conquered from Egypt.  [Source 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt%E2%80%93Israel_Peace_Treaty#History), [Source 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%27s_unilateral_disengagement_plan).
- Map of 2010. The last map is simply absurd as well.  First off Gaza is completely in Arab hands, so it should be properly colored.  The map of West Bank is simply wrong.  Here is the [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:West_Bank_&_Gaza_Map_2007_%28Settlements%29.png), according to Wikipedia.

Comment: The 2010 map is actually correct, and it represents [Areas A and B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bank#Palestinian_administration) (under at least Palestinian civil control). Your statement about Gaza is therefore [factually incorrect](http://unispal.un.org/pdfs/WBmovement-access-OCHAupdate-0912.pdf) - see page 26.

Comment: The 1967 is also correct, according to other sources. It is NOT the the map after the war of independence as the [Gaza strip was occupied by Egypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip#Egyptian_occupation_.281959.E2.80.931967.29) and therefore not Israeli until 1967. The map presents as Palestine the occupied territories. This were the commonly accepted borders (see e.g. [Darthmouh](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/History/israel49.html)) - so again, please correct.

Comment: @Sklivvz Re: 2010 map.  I am afraid you are wrong. The link you provided is a map of settlements in the West Bank from 2006.  I provided a map of who controls what.  However, if you look closely, it is essentially the same exact map. As far as you saying that I am incorrect that Gaza is in Arab hands, please refer to the wikipedia link I provided regarding Israel's withdrawal from Gaza in 2006 (marked Source 2).  In other words, there isn't a single Israeli in Gaza - it is all in Arab hands.  Page 26 of your link is all about West Bank. Thus, my entire statement is 100% correct.

Comment: @Sklivvz Re: 1967 map.  I am correct here as well.  I assume we are talking about the end of 1967, e.g. after the 6 day war (otherwise what's the point of picking that year). At the end of 1967, Israel was in charge of West Bank, Gaza and Sinai.  As per the 2nd source in the "Map of 1967" bullet point.  In fact, compare the 1948 map from the infographic you provided (http://awesome.good.is/transparency/web/1110/cartographic-regression/transparency.jpg) with the 1967 map in the question.  It is the same map!  Thus, I am correct here.

Comment: The 1947 map provided shows Gaza in the hands of Egypt. The 1967 map provided has the same shape but shows Gaza controlled by Israel. Please try to fix your answer based on what the facts are - you can't show a 2007 map for 2010 for example! [Wikipedia is not considered reputable enough here to sustain an answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/289). In general, please refer to reputable, ideally neutral organisations, such as the UNO or to history books. Avoid the military. I am only trying to help you make your answer acceptable to our standards.

Comment: 1946 : "*It might be a better idea to have a map of land owned by Jewish vs Arab hands. I doubt that an accurate map like that exists. *" -> Yes indeed. "* I doubt that an accurate map like that exists.*" British administrations did register land ownership. Here is a map used by UN in 1950 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Palestine#/media/File:Palestine_Land_ownership_by_sub-district_%281945%29.jpg

Comment: @Evargalo The UN source for the map returns 404.

Comment: @AngryHacker : The link from wiki is obsolete, but after some research I found it here on the UN website : https://unispal.un.org/DPA/DPR/unispal.nsf/dcb71e2bf9f2dca585256cef0073ed5d/a73996728ba8b94785256d560060cd1a?OpenDocument Most of the data can be found there http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nli/Hebrew/library/Pages/BookReader.aspx?pid=856390 or there http://www.palestineremembered.com/Acre/Books/Story831.html (this last source is a partisan website, but it shows extensive scans from the genuine document)

Comment: (permalink : https://unispal.un.org/DPA/DPR/unispal.nsf/0/A73996728BA8B94785256D560060CD1A)

Comment: @Evargalo Thanks for the fix.  But all the more it proves my point.  Example. In the link you posted it states that the Beersheba district is 85% public lands, while the 1946 map shows it to be a nearly all Palestinian land.

Comment: @AngryHacker : I agree with you that the map in the claim is not accurate. It correctly depicts all Jewish-owned land but incorrectly colors everything else as "Palestinian land" as if everything was privately owned by Arabs, and forgetting about public areas (most but not all are deserts) and land owned by other entities (Druzes, Greek Orthodox Church, British citizens...). However, your sentence "*It might be a better idea to have a map of land owned by Jewish vs Arab hands. I doubt that an accurate map like that exists.*" should be corrected. Maybe with a link to the UN map that do exist.

Comment: @Evargalo I've added your link to the paragraph in question.

Comment: You argue __There was no country of Palestine. The entire area was under British control.__ by this argument so There was no country of India.

Comment: By the same argument there is no "country of Scotland" since the entire area is under British control. Fact is, in 1946 there was a political entity called Palestine with borders as depicted in the first map.

Comment: Technically speaking, the 1947 map **did** "come to be" - in 1948, and for about one day - then there was war and the losers lost some land, as was pretty typical in wars at that time - don't forget that tons of borders had just been shifted around in Europe by the winners of WW2 just 3 years earlier.

Answer (score 25):

The maps from the original question are incorrect on the points that Sklivvz points out in his excellent answer, but correct on many important parts. The greatest fault of the original map is the lack of information about the cause, and that it does not show any disengagement by Israel - which did happen. The borders did not grow uniformly through time, sometimes the borders contracted, and the increase of land area happened in bursts: twice the result of (unsolicited) war, once the result of mutually signed agreements.

As Sklivvz points out in the end of his answer: "It would be wildly misleading, though, not to mention that Israel was involved in many of these wars as a [defending party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Israel) and that they have been giving back control to the [Palestinian National Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_National_Authority) of some of the land".

I want to explain the shortcomings of the map from the original answer with different maps, but I'd like to start off with the perception that land was stolen unilaterally by Israel as depicted here:
[image: Anti-jewish depiction of border changes in Israel]
(source: http://whatreallyhappened.com/WRHARTICLES/mapstellstory.html)

The reason this is actually not 'what really happened' is that the Israeli government did not go out and claim this land, they actually conquered as a result of several wars for which they were the defending party, not the aggressor, from 1948 through to 1980. Explained for the [1948 Arab-Israeli war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Arab%E2%80%93Israeli_War) by this map:

[image: Vox map of 1948 Arab-Israeli War]
(source: http://www.vox.com/2014/7/17/5902177/9-questions-about-the-israel-palestine-conflict-you-were-too)

The borders changed again in 1948 after Israel, Egypt, Jordan, and Syria emerged from the six-day war, instigated by Nasser [with great support of Arabs in several countries](http://youtu.be/YZYBUdzJuqI?t=49m21s). The events leading up to this war included the following:

- [Egyptian Troop Build-up in Sinai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_the_Six-Day_War#Egyptian_Troop_Build-up_in_Sinai)
- [Removal of U.N. peacekeepers from Egypt by the Egyptian government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_the_Six-Day_War#Removal_of_U.N._peacekeepers_from_Egypt)
- [The Straits of Tiran closure closing off supply routes to Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_the_Six-Day_War#The_Straits_of_Tiran_closure)
- [Jordan support for Egypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_the_Six-Day_War#Jordan_joins_Egypt)
- [Arab States' armed forces mobilizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_the_Six-Day_War#Arab_states_preparations).

An informative documentary about this war is [Six Days in June](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZYBUdzJuqI). After these six days, the map looked like this:

[image: BBC News Six Days War - after]

Following the Camp David accords in 1979, the Sinai was handed back to Egypt in the [Egypt-Israel Peace Treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt%E2%80%93Israel_Peace_Treaty), shrinking the borders of Israel down (one of the things that never happens in the original series of maps offered in this question).

The 2000 map resulted from the [Oslo agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_I_Accord), but is grossly understating the amount of Palestinian land resulting from those accords. The reason it looks so patchy is because of [the sub-division of the west bank into areas A, B, and C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bank_Areas_in_the_Oslo_II_Accord). The following map illustrates the sub-division of land on the West Bank as agreed upon in 2000:
[image: West Bank areas A, B and C]

Finally, one important part left out in the original map of occupied territory is the unilateral [disengagement from Gaza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%27s_unilateral_disengagement_plan) that Israel effectuated in 2005 as part of a road to peace. This disengagement included the destruction of Israeli settlements by the Israeli army, leaving no Israeli occupying force in Gaza. However, ccess between Egypt and Gaza as well as Isreal and Gaza is tightly [restricted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockade_of_the_Gaza_Strip).

Comment: Good answer, but could you put in a brief description of what Areas A, B, and C are and which of them correspond with the original map?  I *think* it's both A and B, but I can't tell.

Comment: It seems like you have some text missing, as your answer goes directly from talking about 1948 to a map from 1967, without any accompanying explanation. Also (not a criticism of your answer) is it anachronistic to put a Palestinian flag on an infographic for 1947?

Comment: @Benjol I'll take a look and see what I can do to bridge the gap. Interesting point on the 1947 infographic - which of course has many flaws. It seems to have been used since 1947 by pro-nation palestinians though http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_flag.

Comment: Whether Gaza is still an occupied territory or not is at least debatable. https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2015/07/02/does-israel-actually-occupy-the-gaza-strip/?utm_term=.364ed1d7d7f0

Comment: @Evargalo I gather that a blockade can also be called an occupation - okay. In that case, it would at least be nice to include a partial non-occupation under most interpretations of 'occupation' in the original/misleading map in the question. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: "Defending party"? The "defenders" came [heavily armed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arms_shipments_from_Czechoslovakia_to_Israel_1947%E2%80%9349) from outside the region.

Comment: @KeithMcClary : not necessarily a contradiction...

Comment: I would say a tautology - how will you defend without arms?

Comment: Who was the agressor and who was the defending party is controversial in several wars. I think there could be a consensus that in may 1948 Arabs were the agressors (invading into Israel), but in november-december 1947 it was less clear (fighters were mostly people already installed in Palestine, Arab muslims on one side and Jews on the other side)

Comment: @Evargalo, there is no fantasy re-definition of the word "occupied", as you try to present. Does US occupy Iran? or Ukraine occupies Russia? This just makes no sense. Does Huties occupy today Israel? This is basically your strange definition of the word.

Comment: @dEmigOd : I don't know where you found fantasy, but "occupying power" is precisely defined in international law, not by myself : https://www.icrc.org/en/doc/resources/documents/misc/634kfc.htm The answers of your three rhetoretical questions are : no, no, no. e.g., the US don't control the movements of Iran's population.

Comment: @Evargalo, I quote from the link: "Article 42 of the 1907 Hague Regulations (HR) states that a " territory is considered occupied when it is actually placed under the authority of the hostile army. The occupation extends only to the territory where such authority has been established and can be exercised. "

Comment: @Evargalo, moreover "The normal way for an occupation to end is for the occupying power to withdraw from the occupied territory or be driven out of it. However, the continued presence of foreign troops does not necessarily mean that occupation continues."

Comment: @Evargalo, I see troop presence is being claimed to whatever, and blockade is not defined as occupation, despite your claims.

Comment: @dEmigOd : jurists' interpretation has been constant for decades on this subject : Amnesty : https://www.amnesty.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/mde150072009en.pdf Un GA : https://press.un.org/en/2023/ga12572.doc.htm Red Cross : https://www.icrc.org/en/document/ihl-occupying-power-responsibilities-occupied-palestinian-territories

Comment: @Evargalo, I'm not buying the anti-Israel organizations definition, unless you enforce this definition to the whole world and state that Houties occupy Israel, since they effectively stopped any maritime shipment through Red Sea to Israel. Ukraine is occupying Russia, as it does not allow the passage of Russian civilian planes through its airspace etc., etc.

Comment: @dEmigOd You can try to be right alone against the whole world, but international definitions exist for a reason.

Comment: @Evargalo, unfortunately, your "international" definition is somehow different from the definition in wikipedia or in a dictionary. This is called a newspeak. I even silent about the definition in other "official" UN languages, which are totally different, but not in the direction of the newspeak.

Comment: @Evargalo, moreover, if we engage in the newspeak, I want to understand: since Houties occupy Israel, why are they waging a war on Gaza? Is this a religious conflict or territorial?

Comment: @dEmigOd : If you want to ask a different question, please use the "Ask" button on the main page, and refrain to use the comment section under another question.