# Did David Attenborough say that Israelis are more cruel than any animal?

Tags: quotes, israel

Did Sir David Attenborough say the following about Israelis? From [Israel has lost both the battle and the war](http://www.arabnews.com/news/613156) (Wikipedia article on [Arab News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_News)), but the quote has been circulating elsewhere as well:

> I am unaware of any animal that is as cruel as Israelis— not even
>   crocodiles. They bomb schools, hospitals, refugee camps, orphanages,
>   UN feeding stations, water works, power plants, ambulances, kids
>   playing on the beach. They put millions of people in a siege. They
>   shoot children going to school. They kidnap kids and harvest their
>   organs. They inject prisoners with disease pathogens before releasing
>   them. They murder by land, sea and air and worst of all, they slander
>   their defenseless victims as ‘terrorists’.

Comment: "They kidnap kids and harvest their organs"??? Is anyone serious seriously contending that David Attenborough would have said that? I doubt it. FWIW, have a link: http://toxicdrums.blogspot.ch/2014/08/the-david-attenborough-hoax.html (not peer-reviewed, just the third result for "david attenborough israel animals")

Comment: Is this notable?

Comment: @Sklivvz being published in a newspaper would make it more notable than something published on some person's personal website, such as http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/did-jews-take-over-73-of-their-land-from-palestinians

Comment: I'd be happy for this question to be put on hold temporarily because the subject's brother died yesterday. I wouldn't want anyone emailing him now to verify or debunk the claim.

Comment: @Andrew, I wouldn't want anyone emailing him ever to ask him that. It would be rather insulting...

Comment: @AndrewGrimm the claim you link is believed by a lot of Arabs. I'm simply not sure that anyone takes this seriously - sure, it's in a newspaper, but...

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't read like  Attenborough (nor his brother Dickie).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An anonymous person wrote a comment on July 21, 2014 on [PressTV.ir](http://www.presstv.ir/detail/2014/07/21/372201/israel-drops-phosphorus-bombs-on-gaza/) that uses David Attenborough name. That comment was strongly upvoted and people made Facebook memes out of it.

Given that social media activity the Arab News took it as fact for their article on August 8, 2014.

The blog [Toxic Drums](http://toxicdrums.blogspot.de/2014/08/the-david-attenborough-hoax.html) analyses the case in more detail.

Anyone could have written that comment and there's no reason to believe that it was David Attenborough. If David Attenborough wanted to say something on the issue the 88 year old would likely write an OPed in a newspaper instead of commenting on an Iranian news website.

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine him describing crocodiles as "cruel".

Comment: That struck me as well. Lends credences that it is someone else. Specifically, when I think of crocodiles and Jew-hating I immediately think of Egypt, but I am sure a lot of countries around there share that characteristic.

Comment: For example, Ammit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammit) is an old Egyptian god with the head of a crocodile and "embodied all that the Egyptians feared", often described as cruel.

Comment: Attenborough would almost certainly not describe any animal as cruel, as that would be to anthropomorphise the animal.  Cruelty is a purely human concept that implies malice aforethought that animals simply don't possess.  They kill to survive, simple as that.